# Error handling table generated by os.time() Lua

Tags: date, lua, formatting, lua-table

```
table.concat(os.date("*t"), ":",4,6)
```

any idea why ^this^ or ˇthisˇ

```
test = os.date("*t")
table.concat(test, ":" , 4 , 6 )
```

does not work?

> input:3: invalid value (nil) at index 4 in table for 'concat'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table.concat` works on numerically indexed table. Whereas the output of `os.date '*t'` would be a [table like](http://codepad.org/Kxx341wy):

```
hour    18
min 20
wday    1
day 2
month   3
year    2014
sec 49
yday    61
isdst   false
```

Comment: So "hour"/"min" and so on is also part of the table that means table isn't the best way to split time to hours mins and secs... Many thanks I'll find my way around...

Comment: @IsawU If you can tell what you want to do, I'd be able to help you. As for storing dates, you can store the epoch number and format it as per your needs.

Comment: It is nothing special just a simple program to learn tables-now I guess it will be more like string manipulation... File in/output, tables and string manipulation is a thing I never tried before...

Answer (score 0):

Although not the answer to your direct question, I suspect you are trying to do is retrieve the time separated by colons.

The best way to do that is `os.date"%H:%M:%S"`

The formatting options are very flexible and use the [C strftime format](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime).